# Exporting IIS 5 settings

Tags: iis, metabase

I'm being asked to produce an inventory of applications on a Win2k/IIS5 server.

Is there a way to back up the metabase into a human-readable format?  (xml is close enough). I read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302573, but in one of the links it talks about the metabase.bin file, which doesn't sound like it's going to be human-readable.

Can anyone point me at a how-to or recommend tools?  This is a one-time-only thing, so we don't really want to buy anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need the old MetaEdit utility (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301386) to do what you're trying to do. IIS 5 (and 4) used a binary format for the metabase, and there wasn't any notion of "portability" like there is with the IIS 6 metabase. I'd be careful about importing anything you export-- there's no guarantee with IIS 5 that server-specific information won't be in an export (and thus not be importable onto another server computer).

Comment: Thanks - we're not trying to move it to another machine, just need to know what's there, and I don't have direct access to the machine.